# CGI script, save `printf` to file using Terminal (OS X)

Tags: macos, post, terminal, save, printf

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599535/os-x-post-reciver-server) earlier about how to read a `POST request` with your own local server (On OS X)

Now my problem is that i can't save the POST Data received on my server.

I currently use `while true; do nc -l 10000 < /dev/null ; printf '\n\n\n'; done` to receive and display the POST Message sent from my iOS device, and it workes perfectly.

But how can i save the `printf` output?

I tried using a local `.sh` file and send the `POST Request` withe the following code (with no success):

```
#!/bin/sh

printf 'Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n'
cat > /MYPATH/post-data
echo OK
```

I also tried to save the file directly from Terminal (also without success):

```
while true; do nc -l 10000 < /dev/null ; printf 'Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' >> /MYPATH/post-data echo OK; done
```

However the code I used in Terminal actually created the `post-data` file, but only with the `Content-type: text/plain` text, and not the actual POST (Terminal displayed the post tho).

I need this answered **tonight**, so I would really appreciate it if you could help me on this one.

Basic roundup: I want to save the `printf` that contains the POST Request data to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are wanting this:

```
while true; do (printf 'Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n'; nc -l 10000 < /dev/null) >> /MYPATH/post-data; echo OK; done
```

Not sure which side you want the Content-type on...